# Bug in SumConvergence

Tags: bugs, special-functions, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and fixed in 12.0.0**

Version 11.2.0.0 on MacBook Pro:

```
w[n_] := 2^(-1 + n) QPochhammer[-1, 3/2, n]
Print["Auto:     ", SumConvergence[w[n], n]]
Print["Ratio:    ", SumConvergence[w[n], n, Method -> "RatioTest"]]
```

Yields True and False respectively. Auto is apparently wrong as suggested by:

```
ListPlot[Log[Table[w[n], {n, 1, 100}]]]
```

and also by hand-calculating the ratio test.

Comment: Seems to be also the case in 11.3

Comment: Perhaps, time to  add "bugs" tag and header, and  report to Wolfram, Inc.

Comment: How do I report it?

Comment: This also occurs in V10.0.1 on Mac OS X. Adding the `bugs` tag.

Comment: [To report a bug.](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback)

Comment: An old bug, I see it in V8.0.4 on Win7x64.

Comment: Bug report sent

Comment: I am getting `False` in both cases now (*12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019*).

Comment: False & False are performed in version 12.0 on Windows 10. No bug.